# Issues with MediaPlayer and RenderTargetBitmap getting a frame image from video

Tags: c#, rendertargetbitmap

I'm trying to use `MediaPlayer`to get a frame from video as an image.

```
MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
_mediaPlayer.ScrubbingEnabled = true;
_mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri("c:\\Sample.mp4"));
_mediaPlayer.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(_mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoWidth, _mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
```

I had to use `Sleep(1000)`, otherwise I get an error. Is there a solution or do I have to find another way maybe better than `MediaPlayer`?

Comment: You could wait for the events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer?view=netcore-3.1 or use ffmpeg

Comment: Yes i solved waiting  the opened event, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `Open`, the media *is being* opened, but depending on the size of the media this may take a certain amount of time. Accessing the media immediately or waiting for a fixed amount of time is will lead to erroneous behavior. Instead, you should subscribe to the [`MediaOpened`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.mediaopened?view=netcore-3.1) event *before* opening the media.

```
_mediaPlayer.MediaOpened += OnMediaOpened;
```

When the `MediaOpened` event is fired and `OnMediaOpended` is called, the media is loaded and ready to interact with. In the event handler, you should go to the position and render the bitmap.

```
private void OnMediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // ... your drawing code.
}
```

Please keep in mind, that loading the media can also fail. To handle this case, you can subscribe to the [`MediaFailed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.mediafailed?view=netcore-3.1) event, otherwise the bitmap will not be created and you might not be aware why.